# How to stop the repeating function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

- This javascript function first time, it gives alert as 00 11 22
  33(ie. normal)
- when i was call the function 2nd time, it give alert as 00 11 22 22 33 33 33
- List item when i was call the function 3rd time, it gives alert as 00 11 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 33
- but my need is i called n'th time also the first result should come thank you in advance

---

```
function exampleAddOption1(val, dat, pr) {
    var cases = 0;
    var bottles = 0;
    var price = 0;
    alert("00");
    $('#itt').append('<option value = "' + dat + '">' + val + '</option>');
    $('#autocomplete').val("");
    $(".logindiv").css("display", "block");
    $("#case").focus();
    $("#case").keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            $("#bottle").focus();
        }
    });
    $("#bottle").keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            $(".lgbtn").focus();
        }
    });
    alert("11");
    $(".lgbtn").click(function () {
        if ($("#case").val() != "") {
            cases = $("#case").val();
        } else {
            cases = 0;
        }
        if ($("#bottle").val() != "") {
            bottles = $("#bottle").val();
        } else {
            bottles = 0;
        }
        $("#case").val("");
        $("#bottle").val("");
        $(".logindiv").css("display", "none");
        $('#qty').append('<option value = "' + cases + ',' + bottles + '">' + cases + 'Cs, ' + bottles + 'Btl</option>');
        cases = 0;
        bottles = 0;
        $(".logindiv2").css("display", "block");
        $("#price").val(pr);
        $("#price").focus();
        alert("22");
        $("#price").keydown(function (e) {
            var code = e.which;
            if (code == 13) {
                $(".lgbtn2").focus();
            }
        });
        $(".lgbtn2").click(function () {
            alert("33");
            price = $("#price").val();
            $('#amt').append('<option value = "' + price + '">' + price + '</option>');
            $(".logindiv2").css("display", "none");
            $("#autocomplete").focus();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That's what happens when you bind event handlers inside other event handlers.

Comment: Indentation would help a lot to understand the code. Please fix it, nobody will read this

Comment: Split your code into small undestandable pieces that others can read it

Comment: Please reduce this down to about 20 or 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be reduced to the following snippet.

```js
$("#test1").click(function () {
    console.log("1");
    $("#test2").click(function () {
        console.log("2");
        $("#test3").click(function () {
            console.log("3");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" type="button" value="test1"/>
<input id="test2" type="button" value="test2"/>
<input id="test3" type="button" value="test3"/>
```

Click the buttons in the order test1, test2, test3. The test1 click adds a handler for test2. The test2 click adds a handler for test3. The console log will show 1, 2, 3. Again, click the buttons in the order test1, test2, test3. The test1 click adds another handler for test2. Test2 now has two handlers. When test2 is clicked, two handlers are executed with each adding an additional handler for test3. Test3 now has three handlers. WHen test2 is clicked, three handlers are excuted. The console log will show 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3.

One possible solution is remove existing click event handlers before adding new click event handlers. The following snippet demostrates this solution.

```js
$("#test1").click(function () {
    console.log("1");
    $("#test2").off("click");
    $("#test2").click(function () {
        console.log("2");
        $("#test3").off("click");
        $("#test3").click(function () {
            console.log("3");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1" type="button" value="test1"/>
<input id="test2" type="button" value="test2"/>
<input id="test3" type="button" value="test3"/>
```

Click the buttons test1, test2, test3. Console shows 1, 2. 3. Again, click the buttons test1, test2, test3. Console shows 1, 2, 3 as desired.